# How to move the desktop background?

Tags: desktop, system-settings

The situation I face is that I have a wallpaper that fills the screen but shows the wrong part of the actual image. So I am wondering whether I could possibly move the image so it shows me the proper section I'd like to see.

Comment: Do you want to make sure that you see the whole picture on the background or do you want to select a part of it to display on the whole screen?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the size of your screen, what resolution you are using on that screen, and what the resolution and size of your wallpaper is.

Comment: I fully understand your plight. I have this now, The problem is that in XP I could grip the artwork and move it on its x+y-axis. or up and down. but I cannot remember how I did it. I feel that it was in the settings part, but so very long ago, maybe it will jog somebody's memory, I am going back maybe fifteen or twenty years ago.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of only two options, assuming that you need full control over which part of the image that appears on the display:

- You can crop and/or resize the image using an image editor, so that it fits your display.
- You can use my recently released app [Fresco](http://glimmir.com/app1.html).

Note: I'm not aware of any other solution, tool or app that lets you select an arbitrary part of an image for desktop use.

Comment: I hate simply adding "Thanks!" comments, but your app actually does what I expected rather perfectly, without any gimmicks and/or bugs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-Click on the Desktop.
2. Change Desktop Background.
3. Click on the Photo you want as your Desktop Background.
4. **Choose "Fit to Screen" or "Center."**
5. Close System Preferences.

***You can also get here thru:***
1. Apple icon (Top-Left of Computer).
2. System Preferences.
3. Desktop & ScreenSaver.

Comment: This does not answer the question